# Why my simple animation using position in Swift is inverted?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I just want to make a very simple animation to move an `UIButton`.

I have this piece of code :

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
     shieldButton!.frame.origin.x += shieldButton!.bounds.width
}, completion: { finished in
     shieldButton!.hidden = true
 })
```

But the button move **from** the position that I want it move **to** it's original position...

I really don't understand...

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image to make things clearer? I personally don't understand what you want to do

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're describing. The above code seems to work fine. Please try to create a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added an image to explain my problem...